# How to prevent CMake from explicitly linking system libraries?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cmake

I'll use [CMake's example project](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/tutorial/A%20Basic%20Starting%20Point.html) as an example. So I have this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

# set the project name
project(Tutorial)

# add the executable
add_executable(Tutorial tutorial.h)

set_target_properties(Tutorial PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
```

After I generate the solution, when I open the solution in Visual Studio and go to `Project Properties - Configuration Properties - Linker - Input - Additional Dependencies`, I see that it links a lot of libraries :
[image]

I'd like to prevent user32.lib from linking for this specific project(not for every project in the solution). I tried googling and found this thread: [How to avoid linking to system libraries](https://discourse.cmake.org/t/how-to-avoid-linking-to-system-libraries/2581). But I couldn't find a solution.

The reason I'd like to do this is because I'm trying to not link user32.lib in my test project, so I can do the link substitution(also known as link seam) technique to be able to provide my own implementation in the test project, to mock the system calls to be able to test classes that do these system calls.
It already works: I removed the library in the Visual Studio's project properties(as well as added it to the list in the `Ignore Specific Default Libraries` property), but the problem is that every time the solution is regenerated, the linking of the library gets restored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this question and the answer because I couldn't find the solution on google, and it seems there wasn't one.

Ok, so to fix the problem, all I need to do is:

```
SET(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES "")
```

And that's it! Now CMake won't explicitly link all the libraries in the first screenshot in the question.

But Even after setting this line to be empty, the whole solution keeps working: it actually still links all those libraries because of `%(AdditionalDependencies)` and the `Inherit from parent or projects defaults` checkbox:
[image]

And now to actually exclude the user32.lib from linking in my the project, I do:

```
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(${MY_PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "/NODEFAULTLIB:User32.lib")
```

Comment: Note that `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` must be set in a toolchain file, [according to its own documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_STANDARD_LIBRARIES.html). Uses outside of toolchain files might break without warning.

Comment: Yep. Well, I think this might be the only way to achieve this. Otherwise these libraries will be there in the end, and there's no other way not to link them, other than remove them from Additional Dependencies there. When I think about it, I think it's a mistake to put these libraries in the `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` variable in the first place(at least for MSBuild), because it already links those libraries by default, unless you tell it not to explicitly.

Comment: There does _exist_ another way, though it's not exactly cleaner... you can use the `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_LAUNCHER` variable on Ninja as an escape hatch to make arbitrary modifications to a compiler/linker invocation. Add/remove flags in your custom script as you see fit and then run the resulting command.

Comment: But as your environment does include those libraries by default, I think you would be fine to put `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES "")` in a toolchain file and then use `target_link_options(${MY_PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE "/NODEFAULTLIB:User32.lib")` in your project.

Comment: @AlexReinking you don't use it on Ninja. You use it on cmake for configuration step, passing as an argument: `-DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES=""`.